# Почему нельзя получить Hashtable прямо из функции PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

... или что я делаю не так?

```
function GetHashtableFromJsonText {
  [OutputType([System.Collections.Hashtable])]
  param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string]$JsonString
  )
  $table
  try {
    $table = (ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $JsonString -AsHashtable -Depth 3)
  }
  catch {
    return $null
  }
  return ($table -is [System.Collections.Hashtable]) ? $table : $null
}

# Пробую привести JSON к Hashtable
$jsonText = '{ "foo": 123 }'

Write-Host "---1---"
$ht = GetHashtableFromJsonText -JsonString $jsonText
Write-Host "PSTypeNames: $($ht.PSTypeNames)"
Write-Host "`$ht.GetType().FullName: $($ht.GetType().FullName)"
# PSTypeNames: System.Object[] System.Array System.Object
# $ht.GetType().FullName: System.Object[] ◀ ◀ ◀ ◀ ◀

Write-Host "---2---"
# Пробую так и наконец получаю Hashtable               ▼ ▼ ▼ ▼ ▼ ▼ ▼ ▼ ▼ ▼ ▼ ▼ ▼
$ht = GetHashtableFromJsonText -JsonString $jsonText | Group-Object -AsHashTable
Write-Host "PSTypeNames: $($ht.PSTypeNames)"
Write-Host "`$ht.GetType().FullName: $($ht.GetType().FullName)"
# PSTypeNames: System.Collections.Hashtable System.Object
# $ht.GetType().FullName: System.Collections.Hashtable ◀ ◀ ◀ ◀ ◀
```

[Playground PS](https://code.labstack.com/l7TSTOLk)

Почему в первом варианте(без `Group-Object`) возвращается `System.Object[]`, ведь внутри функции - это явно Hashtable, но в переменную, по какой-то причине, попадает не то что ожидается?

Comment: Какая версия Powershell используется? Я много лет использую версии 2,3,4 для целей обратной совместимости. Не уверен, что существует switch -AsHashtable для этого командлета. Возвращаемый объект согласно объявленному в функции значении становится [System.Collections.Hashtable], однако по причине отсутствия нужного switch параметра уходит в catch блок и return возвращает объект нужного типа, при этом, содержащий null.

Comment: @KirillPashkov Версия последняя `PowerShell 7.2`, по ссылке из примера на Playground ничего в catch-блок не уходит - там версия 7.1. А [-AsHashtable там есть](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-7.2)